# eclipse package with dot not representing directory structure

Tags: java, eclipse, package

In Eclipse you can create a package name with dots in it.

I.e danny.com.app

I would have thought this would create a directory structure of  app/com/danny, but eclipse create a package name call danny.com.app with with no directory structure representing this

Please can some explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, package names always go "a.b.c"

I guess: your package is simply **empty** so far. I think that some settings control if eclipse creates an empty directory as soon as you create a package.

Thus: see what happens when you add something into that package. I am pretty sure eclipse will then create the a/b/c directory in your filesystem.

But maybe your problem is that you are using the eclipse **package** view to look at your project.

Thing is: eclipse has **different** views that you can use to inspect your project. The package explorer ... shows **packages**, whereas the **file explorer** shows the actual file system folders, contents.

Comment: I have tried this, but it still show the name danny.com.app as a package name, not package structure.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I went into windows explorer and it have created a directory structure. I just cannot see it in eclipse. Maybe I need to play around with the views

Comment: That's exactly what an IDE is for: Showing you packages. Don't even look for folders, as folders are just a means to store the packages on disk (since the file system doesn't know anything about packages, classes, or other programming language constructs). You as a developer should never care about the underlying folders. You care about packages and classes.

Comment: @Bananeweizen True, or not true. A developer understands that he is working with different levels of abstraction. Most of the time, you are probably fine with a package view; but alone the fact that eclipse offers you *other* views indicates that, well, sometimes, using the "package view" abstraction isn't sufficient.